# Python: Multiline User Input, Last Word of Previous Line Is Joined to First Word of Next Line

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

The code is supposed to create a dictionary that counts the number of occurrences for a word in a body of text. This is doing using a While loop,  Try block with EOFError exception and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> when the program is done looping through the text.

```
from collections import Counter


print("Enter/Paste your multiline / paragraph of text. Hit Ctrl + D to run it ")
print("DO NOT PRESS ENTER OR CTRL+V AFTER THE FIRST TIME YOU DROP IN AND RUN YOUR TEXT ")

#DO NOT PUT IN TEXT IN input() TEXT WILL JUST APPEAR OVER AND OVER AGAIN AND LOOK ANNOYING

work_on_this_string_built_from_loop = "" # this initializes out of the loop and adds 
                                         # text from input as a single lined string
while True: # the loop will always = True so this creates an infinite loop
    print("DO NOT PRESS ENTER OR CTRL+V AFTER YOU HAVE INITIALLY RAN YOUR TEXT ")
    print("INSTEAD HIT CTRL + D TO RUN IT AFTER TEXT IS INPUTTED")
    print()
    print("THE OUTPUT ABOVE IS NOT THE FINAL RESULT IT IS NOT DONE YET")
    print("IT IS ONLY  OUTPUT FROM THE FIRST PARAGRAPH OR LINE BREAK ")
    try:
        multi_lined_input = input("\n") # blank screen of input will appear after text is pasted in
        work_on_this_string_built_from_loop+=multi_lined_input
        print(f"line is equal to {work_on_this_string_built_from_loop} ") # INPUTS FILE/USER INPUT AS A SINGLE LINED STRING

        print()

        print()
        print(work_on_this_string_built_from_loop.split('\n'))


        frequency_of_words_dict = dict(  Counter( work_on_this_string_built_from_loop.split() )  )



        print()


    except EOFError as error : # this allows for quiting the program using CTRL + D
                               # once the error is excepted, the program ends and this
                               #causes the break statement to execute and the loop ends
        print("ITERATING THROUGH EXCEPTION")

        print(frequency_of_words_dict)
        for i in frequency_of_words_dict.items():
            print(i)
        break


print("PROGRAM COMPLETE")

print(f"the length of words in entry is : {len(work_on_this_string_built_from_loop.split())}")
```

But when I copy and paste text into the program, it joins the last word of a line with the first word of the line after it.

Example:

```
Example string used below

You may charge a reasonable fee for copies of or *providing
access* to or distributing Project Gutenberg-tm electronic works 
provided that

Example Output: 
{'You': 1, 'may': 1, 'charge': 1, 'a': 1, 'reasonable': 1, 'fee': 1, 
'for': 1, 'copies': 1, 'of': 1, 'or': 2,
'*providingaccess*': 1, 'to': 1, 
'distributing': 1, 'Project': 1, 
'Gutenberg-tm': 1, 'electronic': 1, '*worksprovided*': 1, 'that': 1}

('You', 1)
('may', 1)
('charge', 1)
('a', 1)
('reasonable', 1)
('fee', 1)
('for', 1)
('copies', 1)
('of', 1)
('or', 2)
('*providingaccess*', 1)
('to', 1)
('distributing', 1)
('Project', 1)
('Gutenberg-tm', 1)
('electronic', 1)
('*worksprovided*', 1)
('that', 1)
```

How can I split up the last word of the previous line and the first word of the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you process the input, you're removing the line feeds.  As you append the lines to `work_on_this_string_built_from_loop`, append a space.  If you're worried about a superfluous space, then check for that condition.

```
    work_on_this_string_built_from_loop +=     \
        multi_lined_input + ('' if multi_lined_input == ' ' else ' ')
```

Comment: This seems to work thank you. Since I still have a lot to learn, what is the name of the type of syntax you used  for                                          ``` ('' if multi_lined_input == ' ' else ' ')  ```                                                 So I can study it and learn how to use it. I appreciate when I find new routes to go down and learn since I'm mostly self teaching.

Comment: That is the [ternary operator](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-ternary-operator).  This also exists in C, C++, JAVA, and many other helpful languages.